# Python generator behaviour

Tags: python, iterator, generator

```
import itertools
ws=[]
subs=[]
set_subs=[]
for i in xrange(int(raw_input())):
    S=raw_input()
    l=len(S)
    subs.append(S[i:j+1] for i in xrange(l) for j in xrange(i,l))
```

input:

```
2
aab
aac
```

now both `subs[0]` and `subs[1]` give me same result.

```
print list(subs[0])
>>>['a','aa','aac','a','ac','c']
print list(subs[1])
>>>['a','aa','aac','a','ac','c']
```

whereas `list(subs[0])` should have been `['a','aa','aab','a','ab','b']`

I vaguely understand why this is happening. What do I do to make `subs[0]` and `subs[1]` actually different.

**NOTE**: changing the line

```
subs.append(S[i:j+1] for i in xrange(l) for j in xrange(i,l))
```

with

```
subs.append([S[i:j+1] for i in xrange(l) for j in xrange(i,l)])
```

is not an option

Comment: just an advise: you shouldn't reuse `i` as variable in your generator expression. It can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

> Variables used in the generator expression are evaluated lazily when
>   the `__next__()` method is called for generator object (in the same
>   fashion as normal generators). However, the leftmost for clause is
>   immediately evaluated, so that an error produced by it can be seen
>   before any other possible error in the code that handles the generator
>   expression. Subsequent for clauses cannot be evaluated immediately
>   since they may depend on the previous for loop.

`S[i:j+1]` is evaluated when you execute the generator, and at that point `S` has the latest value.

You can use a normal generator instead. Now `ss` is local to `subgen`:

```
import itertools

def subgen(ss):
    l=len(ss)
    for i in xrange(l):
        for j in xrange(i,l):
            yield ss[i:j+1]

subs=[]
for i in xrange(int(raw_input())):
    S=raw_input()
    subs.append(subgen(S))
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is one of the strange features of generator expression. Have a look at [this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#early-binding-versus-late-binding)
In your case it is used late binding and that's why you will get two identical results.